# Why do repeated downloads for Google Chrome setup have each time different hashes?

Tags: google-chrome, checksum

I've tried downloading the setup files for a standalone offline installation version several times in rapid succession. Each next file has an identical size but a different hash. Why is that?

Do they embed some sort of a user identifier into each next download?

The same happens for both EXE and MSI standalone installers.

P.S. I've also noticed that the files have a digital signature with a past date (6 days ago). That means they are generating files on the fly on a machine that is simulated to have a past date. In my book this qualifies as fraud.

Comment: How are you calculating hashes? What about other browsers? Where are you downloading from?

Comment: Different browsers (IE, Firefox), downloading directly from google.com, using a popular tool md5deep to calculate SHA1 hashes. There are never two identical files.

Comment: I've found an installer I have downloaded on August 26 and it has a signature from June 2. We don't know if they are generating these files on the fly, maybe they have a bunch of files and are serving them sequentially. That would explain signatures from the past.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all to find [licenced] software that might include some dynamic payload -- such as for licencing, or for anti-piracy. A 6-day age on in the signature might indicate the pre-signing of a number of files, as a way of keeping a low-water level on the number of available downloads that are ready-to-go. I wouldn't say that would be a fraudulant action, though I would perhaps hope [wishfully] that they have some manually signed package before unsigning, modifying and re-signing automatically. Its something of a requirement for software installers to be signed these days.

Comment: What?  Fraud of what exactly?

Comment: Have you performed an exact binary comparison? What is different each time?

Answer (score 3):

I can not reproduce your claim. Can you provide more details, especially steps on how to reproduce it on my end?

I went to the link to [download Chrome Standalone](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en).

I compared three installers I downloaded for the one user version:

[image: Chrome Standalone One User]

All three installers were bit-for-bit exact copies of each other

```
C:\>fc chromestandalonesetup.exe "chromestandalonesetup (1).exe"
Comparing files ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe and CHROMESTANDALONESETUP (1).EXE
FC: no differences encountered

C:\>fc "chromestandalonesetup (1).exe" "chromestandalonesetup (2).exe"
Comparing files ChromeStandaloneSetup (1).exe and CHROMESTANDALONESETUP (2).EXE
FC: no differences encountered
```